# How to set the current time to "TimeField()" as a default value in Django Models?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, default

The doc says below in [DateField.auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add):

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. ... If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True`:

- For `DateField`: `default=date.today` - `from datetime.date.today()`
- For `DateTimeField`: `default=timezone.now` - `from django.utils.timezone.now()`

So to [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield), I can set the current date and time respectively as [a default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) as shown below:

```py
from datetime import date
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=date.today) # Here
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) # Here
```

Now, how can I set the current time to [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) as a default value as shown below?

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):       # ?
    time = models.TimeField(default=...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *callable*:

```
from django.utils import timezone


def current_time():
    return timezone.now().time()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(default=current_time)
```

each time you define a new `MyModel` and the time is not passed, it will *call* the `current_time` method and thus return the time component of the current (timezoned time).

It is important *not* to use parenthesis, so `default=current_time`, *not* <s>`default=current_time()`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `current_time` without `()` which returns [timezone.now().time()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) to [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) as [a default value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#default) as shown below. *Don't set `current_time()` with `()` because the default time becomes when the Django server starts (Unchanged):

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def current_time(): # Here
    return timezone.now().time()

class MyModel(models.Model): # Don't set "current_time()"
    time = models.TimeField(default=current_time)
```

Be careful, don't set `timezone.now().time()` with `()` to `TimeField()` as a default value as shown below because the default time becomes when the Django server starts (Unchanged):

```py
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model): # Don't set "timezone.now().time()"
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now().time())
```

And, don't set `timezone.now().time` without `()` to `TimeField()` as a default value as shown below because there is an error when running `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model): # Don't set "timezone.now().time"
    time = models.TimeField(default=timezone.now().time)
```

In addition, I don't recommend to use [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and `TimeField()` because they don't work with [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) in `settings.py` as I asked [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383841/how-to-set-the-current-proper-date-and-time-to-datefield-and-timefield-r) while [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) does.