# How to set the current proper date and time to "DateField()" and "TimeField()" respectively as a default value by "TIME_ZONE" in Django Models?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, timezone

The doc says below in [DateField.auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add). *I use **Django 4.2.1**:

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. ... If you want to be able to modify this field, set the following instead of `auto_now_add=True`:

- For `DateField`: `default=date.today` - `from datetime.date.today()`
- For `DateTimeField`: `default=timezone.now` - `from django.utils.timezone.now()`

So, I set [timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) and [date.today](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) to `datetime`'s [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) and `date1`'s [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) respectively and I also set `current_date` which returns `timezone.now().date()` and `current_time` which returns `timezone.now().time()` to `date2`'s `DateField()` and `time`'s [TimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#timefield) respectively as shown below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models
from datetime import date
from django.utils import timezone

def current_date():
    return timezone.now().date()

def current_time():
    return timezone.now().time()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) # Here
    date1 = models.DateField(default=date.today) # Here
    date2 = models.DateField(default=current_date) # Here
    time = models.TimeField(default=current_time) # Here
```

Then, I set `'America/New_York'` to [TIME_ZONE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-TIME_ZONE) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York' # Here

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

But, `date1`'s `DateField()` and `time`'s `TimeField()` show UTC(+0 hours)'s date and time respectively on Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

Next, I set `'Asia/Tokyo'` to `TIME_ZONE` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo' # Here

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

But, `date2`'s `DateField()` and `time`'s `TimeField()` show UTC(+0 hours)'s date and time on Django Admin as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I set the current proper date and time to `DateField()` and `TimeField()` respectively as a default value by `TIME_ZONE` in Django Models?

In addition, `DateField()` and `TimeField()` with [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) or [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) cannot save UTC(+0 hours)'s date and time respectively with any `TIME_ZONE` settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you set `USE_TZ` as `True`.

If `USE_TZ` is set as `True`, regardless of what your `TIME_ZONE` variable is set to, Django will only use the UTC.